# How to generate the #Braintree client token for dropin UI for new customer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, braintree

I have setup a bootstrap site and want to put the `dropin UI` within a `modal box`.

I'm stuck at the part where I need to generate the client token. I've followed the guide as best as I can but I'm not using ruby or node or anything just an html page.

Is there some way I can learn more about how I can generate a client token? Should I be using node? I really just need a button and that's it.

EDIT: I've added everything i currently have besides the rest of the page. I'm just displaying it within a modal.

```
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span>&times;</span>
                                        </button>

                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="/checkout" id="checkout" method="post" name="checkout">
                                            <div id="dropin">
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Pay $10">
                                        </form>
                                        <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js">
                                            var gateway = braintree.connect({
                                                environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                                                merchantId: 'xxx',
                                                publicKey: 'xxx',
                                                privateKey: 'xxx'
                                            });

                                            gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function(err, response) {
                                                var clientToken = response.clientToken
                                            });

                                            gateway.transaction.sale({
                                                amount: '10.00',
                                                paymentMethodNonce: 'nonce-from-the-client',
                                            }, function(err, result) {});
                                        </script>
                                        <script>
                                            var
                                                braintree.setup(
                                                    "xxx",
                                                    'dropin', {
                                                        container: 'dropin'
                                                    });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: add your relevant code here

Comment: You will need to generate your client token on the server using whatever backend language you prefer. Node is always a good choice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Braintree :)

You will need a server for your Braintree integration. If you'd prefer not to build the server-side part yourself, you can use one of Braintree's [partners](https://www.braintreepayments.com/partners) that provide a backend for you e.g. [goodsie](http://goodsie.com/).

**update**

Your current code has a mix of server side and client side JS. You will need to run your server side code (all the code in your first script tag) on a node server using the [`braintree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree) npm module, and then print the `clientToken` into an html template. Drop-in can then initialize — using the client token from your server — and work its magic.

Comment: I want to build the backend myself though. I would rather just use woo-commerce or zoho if i was going to use something out of the box. I tried following documentation with node but again was stuck when i had to generate the token. i think there's something fundamental that i'm missing.

Comment: @ZacharyMoore Please update your question with the code that isn't working for you and we can try to help further. You can also reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)

Comment: @ZacharyMoore I saw that you updated your question, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll also be taking some basic online courses for node which i think will help. this is a great first project for me for sure. thanks again and when i get a working model/modal lol i'll update